# Proftpd permissions for user ftp_root folders

Tags: proftpd

When proftpd is configured to limit each user to a *ftp_root* folder in their home directory:

```
DefaultRoot                     ~/ftp_root
```

What permissions should be applied to the ftp_root folder?

I had read on a setup guide from somewhere that `chmod 777 ftp_root` should be run for each user's *ftp_root* directory but surely it should be more restrictive than that? The proftpd server ensures that users can only access their own *ftp_root* folder but I would like to be sure that the permissions are set correctly on that folder to allow the user to list, upload, download, delete files etc but to restrict to just that user from a security standpoint.